# How to get post that has non zero or greater than zero meta value

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, custom-field, post-meta

How to get post that has non zero or greater than zero meta value

```
$args = array(
'sort_order' => 'asc',
'sort_column' => 'post_title',
'hierarchical' => 1,
'exclude' => '',
'include' => '',
'meta_key'     => 'webinarignitionx_meta_box_select',
'meta_compare' => '!=',
'meta_value'   => 0,
// 'authors' => get_the_author_meta('ID'),
'child_of' => 0,
'parent' => -1,
'exclude_tree' => '',
'number' => '',
'offset' => 0,
'post_type' => 'page',
'post_status' => 'publish'
```

Comment: Greater than zero is non zero, so why differentiate?

Comment: my means how to get posts that has meta value =!0
OR
how to get posts that has meta value =>0

Comment: I know both condition work for same